# Does anyone have an example of playing audio (rtmp) using VLCKit

Tags: beatsmusic

I get my url from the audio endpoint, location and resource in tow, but when I drop the audio into a VLCMediaPlayer/VLCMedia object it fails.  So then I was just trying to get the URL to play in the standard VLC Media Player, no such luck.

However, if I use rtmpdump I can at lest see something is there with the following:

```
rtmpdump -r <api.location> -y <api.resource>
```

I'm only using rtmpdump to see if I even get any data at all, if I change the structure of the call to:

```
rtmpdump -r <api.location> + '/' + <api.resource>
```

it will fail.

This test makes be think the actual media url is not just  **+ '/' +**  and I am formatting the url incorrectly for VLCKit playback, or in the VLC Player proper.

Anyway, does anyone have an example of this?

**update 1**

After following xhochy suggestion of `/?slist=`

And building VLCKit @ version 2.1-stable

The following code will play a stream:

```
#import <VLCKit/VLCKit.h>

self.player = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] init];

VLCMedia *media = [VLCMedia mediaWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<location>/?slist=<resource>"]];

self.player.media = media;
[self.player play];
```

**update 2**

You will also need to codesign the Framework after it's built, the command you are looking for is here:

```
codesign -v -f -s <your 40 char hash or common name> --deep VLCKit.framework/Versions/A
```

Comment: Are you able to play audio files now. Can you please share code how to play audio files. In my case i am able to play the video urls but unable to play the Audio urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play Beats Music in VLC(kit) you need to concatenate the rtmp URL via '/?slist=' so that you have `<location>/?slist=<resource>` as your final URL. You will need a very recent version  of VLCkit (probably best is to build from git) as there some bugfixes needed to make it running smooth.

Comment: Looks like it's trying now, but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS from VLCKit in VLCMedia.m line 779 `NSNumber * number = stringToMetaDictionary[string];
    return number ? [number intValue] : -1;` on that bit. I just built VLCKit this morning. I'll keep trying */?slist=* is more than I knew before. =)

Comment: Ok.. I had to just build v2.1-stable of VLCKit. After that it works like a champ (including using the `/slist=`